# How to send the my sql result to controller in codeigniter as a variable

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

In my mode I am selecting a field as

```
$query1 = $this->db->query("SELECT dPassword 
                    FROM tbl_login
                    WHERE  dEmailID='a@a.in'");
```

How to return `dpassword` as a variable to my controller
I tried this way `return dpassword;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is also fine:

```
if($query1->num_rows() > 0){
    $row = $query1->row();
}
return $row->dPassword;
```

Then if your query was to return more than a single row you could operate on the results like so:

```
foreach($query1->result() as $row){
echo $row->field1;
echo $row->field2;
echo $row->etcetera;
}
```

For single row results i usually return the row directly from the model like so:

```
return $query1->row();
```

Here is an example of this:

```
function select_provider_details($provider_id)
    {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('providers');
        $this->db->where('provider_id', $provider_id);

    $query = $this->db->get();

    if($query->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        $result['success'] = TRUE;
        $result['query'] = $query->row();
    }
    else
    {
        $result['success'] = FALSE;
        $result['error'] = "Provider not found in database";
        $result['errorcode'] = "E003";
        $result['query'] = $query->row();
    }
        return $result;
}
```

Or for a query expected to return multiple results i return the entire results object:

```
return $query1;
```

Answer (score 3):

Check out the Query Results section of the CI manual.  $query1 is set to a mysql resource from the query you executed.  You then need to call additional functions to get the data

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html

```
$dataArray=$query1->result_array();
return $dataArray["dPassword"];
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use tray this.

```
$query1 = $this->db->query("SELECT dPassword  
                    FROM tbl_login 
                    WHERE  dEmailID='a@a.in'"); 

if($query1){
   // if you are working with objects
   return $query1->result();
   // if you are working with arrays try
   return $query1->result_array();
}else{
   return false;
}
```